# Bootstrap3 Two Anchors in each dropdown menu item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a clean Bootstrap3 way to render Two links in each menu Item? I need that to bypass the listing, when the user just wants to add a new entry.

I struggled with no success. Ending up writing this code to render the menu shown in the Picture.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Documents<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for docType in docTypes  %}
            <li>
                <a style="z-index: 10; padding-right: 0;"  href="{{ path('document_new', {'docType': docType.className }) }}">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
                </a>
                <a style="padding-left: 10px; margin-left: 35px; margin-top: -26px;" class="" href="{{ path('document', {'docType': docType.className }) }}">{{ docType.name }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
```

[image]

If it weren't for the negative margins each item'd have two lines.

**Edit**

Here's what happens if I remove the Style attributes in those `<a>` inside each `<li>`
   I wonder if there's a bootstrap3 way to get both actions in the same line, being the icon `document_new` and the Document's name text `document`.

[image]

Comment: Extra links...don't you mean extra list items?

Comment: do you want to use 1 link for 2 actions? `document_new` and `document`?

Comment: I don't want to use one <a> for two actions, I need tow actions in the same line in the menu, The `<a>plus Icon</a>` is `document_new` and the `<a>Text</a>` is the `document`. but, as the picture shows, I need them in the same line. Remove the `Style` attribs in each <a> and it breaks down to two lines, each `<li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove inline styles.

[image]

```
.my-dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {display:inline-block;}
.my-dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:first-child:not(:last-child){padding-right:5px;}
.my-dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:last-child:not(:first-child) {padding-left:5px;}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/masiq/1/edit

Copy / Pasting your last (best) approach.

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:first-child:not(:last-child){
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding-right:5px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:last-child:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-left:40px;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! But it has a problem, with inline-block is that the Anchor does not span to the right, it ends with the text, longer menu items cause a stair like look.

Comment: On larger viewports the line does not break, the width of the dropdown adjusts, on smaller viewports it won't stair step, it will go to the next line, the same as you had before.

Comment: Yes, I can see it not breaking, I didn't make myself clear. the width of the dropdown works fine, but the darker background on hover does not get to the right edge, it only does for the largest line. because the `inline-block` shrinks the `<a>` to its content.

Comment: Disguise it such as .my-dropdown li:hover {background:#f7f7f7;} and try other things: http://jsbin.com/ducen/1/edit

Comment: Thanks! :) still `<a>` does not span the whole line. but the look and feel is ok. you should edit your answer to reflect the {background:#f7f7f7;} then it'd be complete

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xulal/1/edit -- but it won't break into two lines if the length of the text is longer than the viewport. Uses absolute on the first

Comment: you are right, I was dealing with it breaking line.
the position absolute && padding did it best. Please edit your answer :)